# vue js select (vuetify) + axios population

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a stack with vue js (vuetify) + laravel + axios.
I am trying to populate a dropdown select using axios.
I have setup an API route on laravel so I can pull data from database table "Categories".
The api return the following:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "Electronics",
    "category_synonym": "Computer Accessories",
    "created_at": "2020-05-31T20:11:56.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-31T20:11:56.000000Z"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "category_name": "Hardware",
    "category_synonym": "hardware",
    "created_at": "2020-05-31T20:17:13.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-31T20:17:13.000000Z"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "category_name": "Kitchenware",
    "category_synonym": null,
    "created_at": "2020-05-31T20:49:32.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-31T20:49:32.000000Z"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "category_name": "Textile",
    "category_synonym": null,
    "created_at": "2020-05-31T21:29:30.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-31T21:29:30.000000Z"
}
```

]

I would like to put the category_name into a vue js dropdown contained into a foram.
How to make it simply ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify select has `item-text` and `item-value`. You can use these props:

```
<v-select
  label="Category"
  :items="categories"
  item-text="category_name"
  item-value="id"
/>
```

Comment: Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-olwqs?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: ok and how can i count the number of items to potentially hide the field if no elements in the list?

Comment: how do i get back the value of the field being selected ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```html
<v-select v-model="currentCategory" :items="resultFromAPI" item-text="category_name" item-value="id" />
```

To fetch the data with Axios you can try something like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const ajax = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.com/api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

export default
{
  data()
  {
    return {
      categories: [],
      currentCategory: null,
    }
  },
  mounted()
  {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods:
  {
    fetchData()
    {
      ajax.get('/categories').then(response =>
      {
        this.currentCategory = null;
        this.categories = response || [];
      });
    }
  }
}
```